# child button element is getting called on click on parent element

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying out the Ionic app. I have the following simple snippet:

```
  <ion-content padding="true" >
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">   
                     <button ng-click="clickMe()">ClickMe</button>        
     </br>
           <div class="input-label">Test Label</div>
  </label>
</ion-content>
```

Which gives the following UI:

[image: UI]

When I am clicking outside of the `ClickMe` button, `ClickMe` button is pushed up and called the `clickMe()`.

Please help me to understand the reason behind this.

Comment: Label sends interaction to button, you should put the `br` and `div` outside

Comment: http://codepen.io/maurycyg/pen/obYRre I've made a visual presentation, label has red border and div inside has blue and if you click on any of those the click would be send to button. You have to realise the size of elements you are using - maybe instead of overused `DIV` use `SPAN`

Answer (score 2):

That is the property of a [label](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL) that:

> When a LABEL element receives focus, it passes the focus on to its
>   associated control.

If you want to prevent it, you can write a directive:

```
myApp.directive('preventClick', function() {
    return {
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            elemenet.on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And apply it to the `label`

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" prevent-click>
      <button ng-click="clickMe()">ClickMe</button>        
       </br>
       <div class="input-label">Test Label</div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use label** for that. Use any other element.

```
<div class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <button ng-click="clickMe()">ClickMe</button>
    </br>
    <div class="input-label">Test Label</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why he shouldn't use label?

Comment: @maurycy Because of this : When a label element receives focus, it passes the focus on to its associated control.

Comment: And semantically what label was designed for? He SHOULD use label but in different way

Comment: @maurycy Well that's what my solution said in the first place

Comment: Not exactly (sorry I'm picky today, didn't had coffee yet). You omitted the `label` completely

Comment: @maurycy (Not my issue if you didn't had coffee). "When I am clicking outside of the ClickMe button, ClickMe button is pushed up and called the clickMe()" . To prevent the unwanted click trigger, this is the simplest thing OP can do without inviting other issues.

Comment: Now that you quote OP why didn't you quote the question too? It was help me understand not change my DOM